# Objects' color after changing background color in manim

Tags: python, manim

I'm trying to change the background of my Scene in manim video with a `self.camera.background-color= WHITE`, the background changed well but all texts are still white.

Is there any other methods to invert all colors in the scene or we have to define each object's color by a `.set_color(BLACK)` ?? Thanks for responding...still newbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the default colors for all different types of objects in Manim.

```py
from manim import *

config.background_color = "#a0a0a0"
Tex.set_default(color=BLACK)
MathTex.set_default(color=TEAL)
Text.set_default(color=PURE_GREEN)
Square.set_default(color=PURE_BLUE)
Circle.set_default(color=PURE_RED)

class test(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        sq = Square().to_corner(UR)
        circ = Circle().to_corner(UL)
        text = Text("Hello World").to_edge(LEFT)
        tex = Tex(r"Hello \LaTeX").shift(UP)
        mathtex = MathTex(r"a^2+b^2=c^2").shift(DOWN)
        self.add(sq,circ,text,tex,mathtex)
```

[image: test scene]

On the [Manim Discord](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/faq/general.html#where-can-i-find-more-resources-for-learning-manim) server there are some more advanced solution for defining your own color schemes...